# Attaching one face to another

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I'm just beginning to learn Blender, and I ran into a problem. I ended up with two separate meshes in one object. I want to attach their faces together, as if I had drawn and extruded one from the other. In this example, I have an octagonal prism that I want to attach to the face of a cube. How can I do this without remaking one of the meshes?

What I have now:

[image: What I have now]

I know that one way to work around it would be to simply move the meshes together so they overlap, but then they aren't actually properly attached, and won't move together/etc.

[image]

Comment: You will have to modify the geometry somewhat since the bottom piece doesn't have the same number of top vertices as the top piece.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either **Boolean** modificator (in Object mode) or *Intersect* tool (in Edit mode).

1. Start with cylinder passing through cube.
2. Cube and cylinder have different amount of vertices, hence cube should be edited in order to have roughly the same shape as cylinder has. It is *possible* to skip this and create intersection as is, however this way will create Ngons which may be undesired.
   One way to change cube accordingly is to bevel it. Select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, 2 segments, low value of *Offset*.

   [image: beveling cube image]
3. Add 1 loopcut per both sides of the cube. Use *Connect Vertex Path* (<kbd>J</kbd>) tool to connect corner vertices.

   [image: editing geometry of cube image]
4. Select all, in 3D Viewport header choose *Mesh* > *Faces* > *Intersect* tool and in its options (Last Operator panel in the Toolshelf or <kbd>F6</kbd>) select *Self-Intersect*.

   [image: using intersect tool image]
5. Select all again, press <kbd>W</kbd>, choose *Remove Doubles*. Note that you may need to enter higher threshold for *Merge Distance*, like 0.02.

Comment: I'm not seeing the Intersect tool. Is it in some addon?

Comment: @a52 answer updated. This tool is present in Blender 2.72+ and it's located in *Mesh* > *Faces* > *Intersect* or you can press `Space` and type tool's name. See [release video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rwvxusuJXU) for more info on it.

Comment: @a52 also note that you might end up with [non-manifold](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) mesh (because of internal faces). Depending on purposes of the meshes you can handle it in different ways; one of them is to press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`M` and delete faces.